# What is the function of this little red button?

Tags: part-identification, opel

I drive an Opel Corsa, and today I discovered a button under the left storage compartment:

[image]

The button is on the top edge of the storage compartment, and isn't normally seen. I checked the owner's manual and didn't see any reference to it.
Naturally, I switched it on and off, but it didn't seem to change anything.

I have a PIN keyboard installed in by car right above the button, but I don't think they're related (the button seems native to the car, and the PIN keyboard is an add-on).

What is this button?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and I don't know the names of any of the parts I referenced (including "storage compartment" and "PIN keyboard"). Feel free to correct my wrong terms. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. The button you are looking at does not appear to be stock. This is not a normal place for a button to be, in my opinion. I think you'd have to take things apart and trace the wiring back to where it originates and go from there.

Comment: If you turn it off, will the car start?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - I will do no such thing. `:)`

Comment: ROFL! No worries. I don't think you'll damage or destroy anything in the process. Really, we won't be able to tell you what it's about, though. The @HandyHowie suggestion is a good one.

Comment: When you take the PIN keyboard off to reseat it (it's dreadfully fitted), you might see wires going from that to the red switch. For me, that red switch is NOT stock, and I'd guess that it's an immobilizer switch, or a cut-out switch to stop the PIN keyboard working. If it's a stock switch (it isn't), it would be in the manual for the car.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I tried, and yes. I can enter the code and start the car with the button off.

Comment: At the very least can you get to the back of the switch and confirm that it is wired to something?

Comment: Maybe self destruct......?   :)

Comment: It may have been a hidden switch to kill the fuel pump or other critical component to make a thief think the car broke. It may have been disconnected by the previous owner before selling the car.

Comment: Sit someone you don't like in the passenger's seat then hit the button - Do remember to open any sunroof first though....